# Is there a way to use Elastic Beanstalk with multiple ec2 instances with out using loadbalancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently i am using Load Balancing,Auto scaling.Where as another option provided was Single Instance.

But my requirement is to use multiple ec2 instances with out using load balancing,auto scaling.

Can someone has a trick or another way to fulfill my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can choose not to make use of auto-scaling. But how do you plan to make use of multiple instances without a load balancer?

Comment: Ours instances won't get requests from any clients ... where as we use it for our internal purposes @TJ-

Comment: Make it a worker app, not Web app.
Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148852/aws-elastic-beanstalk-multiple-instances-without-aws-elastic-load-balancer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a single instance environment, then manually modify the EC2 Instance's auto scaling group to have multiple instances. Or you can do the other way around. You create an auto scaling envorinment then manually delete the load balancer. Neither of these are robust. If you need custom environment setup, you should rather consider cloud formation.